# redis local SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I installed redis in my rails app. everything seems to work fine and I'm running redis server in console. All the ports match. In my initializer:

```
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
```

in the console:

```
[3] pry(main)> REDIS
=> #<Redis client v3.0.2 for redis://localhost:6379/0>
```

but when I try to set something:

```
[4] pry(main)> REDIS.set("hello", "goodbye")
SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@stacksocial/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:112:in `getaddrinfo'
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. I had edited my hosts file a long time ago so 127.0.0.1 was very custom and wasn't playing nicely with redis. I reverted my hosts file back to the default and it works now.

Comment: Could you please share what default was? Thanks.